# How can i get an element from QUEUE

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
int get(){
        if (head == 0) { 
            return -999; 
        }
        else {
            int v = head->item; 
            link t = head->next;
            delete head; head = t; 
            return v;
        }           
    }
```

Here is my switch case to call get function

```
if (q.get() != -999) {
    cout << q.get() << " element removed from Queue" << endl;
} 
else {
   cout << "nothing to get; queue is empty" << endl;
}
```

when i get an element like 1 from get function, im getting `"nothing to get; queue is empty"`message.

but i am able to get a correct element from the queue, but getting a wrong message. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Your "queue.get()" *changes* the current node.  And you're doing *two* of them: once in the "if", then again for the "cout".  Is this what you really want???

Answer (score 0):

Because you call the get() twice.

once in `if(q.get() != -999)`

another in `cout << q.get() << "element removed from queue" << endl;`

It means you **delete two elements** in your queue.So if your queue has only one element, you will get the empty message.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling `q.get()` **twice** here:

```
if (q.get() != -999) // First time
    cout << q.get() << " element removed from Queue" << endl; // Second time
else
   cout << "nothing to get; queue is empty" << endl;
```

You should instead store the result of `q.get()` to a variable and check it like:

```
int lastValue = q.get();
if (lastValue != -999)
    cout << lastValue << " element removed from Queue" << endl;
else
   cout << "nothing to get; queue is empty" << endl;
```